# How to set in range in hexbin plots pandas?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to set range of y-axis in the following code.My values are [19,20,21,22,23,24.....,40].I want the labels to be starting from of difference 10,starting from 10 upto 40.How should I set that.
I was trying to use x-lim but it is not working.

```
plt.hexbin(p_df['Age'], p_df['Salary'], gridsize = 50,bins ='log',cmap ='BuGn',xlim =(19, 40))
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the range of values to include in the binning, you must use the 'extent' keyword. So to have a hexbin plot with a range between your desired x and y values, you can use,

```
extent=[-x,x,10,40]
```

where x is your included x coordinates.
So your new code would be

```
plt.hexbin(p_df['Age'], p_df['Salary'], gridsize = 50,bins ='log', extent=[-x,x,10,40],cmap ='BuGn')
```